# SQL Update an Set Value

Tags: php, sql, set, sql-update

I'm trying to update my SQL via PHP. So here is my code.
I want to update the values after clicking a button in my form.
So i only want to test it first before i build my whole form.

***PHP:***

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $query = "UPDATE mm_projektschutz SET projektname='Neuername' WHERE id='1' "; }
?>
```

***HTML***

```
<form>
   <input type='submit' value='Speichern' class='save'>
</form>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I need a solution that work :)

Comment: <form action="demo_form.php" method="post">

Comment: So without action and a other php doc its not possible?
I have both code in the same document (php)

Answer (score 0):

If your code is on the same page you should add *action* attribute to the *form* tag link to itself so your php syntax can update.

```
<form action="pagename.php" method="post">
   <input type='submit' value='Speichern' class='save'>
</form>
```